# Github push failing: RPC failed; curl 55 OpenSSL SSL_write: SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN, errno 10053

Tags: git, curl, github, push

I am trying to upload files from command prompt to github repo.

I have already set `git config --global http.postBuffer 15728640` along with `set GIT_TRACE=1` and `set GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1` .

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: GitHub Babel 2.0
< Content-Type: application/x-git-receive-pack-result
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1980 00:00:00 GMT
< Pragma: no-cache
< Cache-Control: no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< X-GitHub-Request-Id: xxxx:xxxx:xxxxxxx:xxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
<
* OpenSSL SSL_write: SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN, errno 10053
* Closing connection 1
error: RPC failed; curl 55 OpenSSL SSL_write: SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN, errno 10053
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

All files are below 50mb each and the total size is ~6bg total. Github has a file size limit of 100mb and repo size of 100gb so I know it's not a size issue. Anything helps, thanks!

Comment: Try to disable the antivirus/firewall software on your Windows.

Comment: Disabled the firewall. Got the same error: `errno 10053`

Comment: forgot to mention @LorinczyZsigmond